# iOS: Parse framework & Facebook OpenGraph

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-opengraph, parse-framework

Has anyone out there integrated Facebook OpenGraph in to your iOS app using the Parse (www.parse.com) framework as your backend?

**My goal is simply to post images to Facebook from my iPhone app using OpenGraph**. From what I can tell, FB will not host the photos themselves - surprisingly - so I'm on the assumption I need my own backend (or Parse's in this case). (If I'm misunderstanding this, please correct me!)

I've spent most of the last day experimenting with the Facebook framework, and **I plan to use Parse for much of my web services in the app, so ideally I would leverage both together** and **NOT introduce a separate backend/webservice** (e.g. Heroku/Rails) just for simple image hosting.

..but either way I fear could get lost down a deep hole trying to implement something that will never work - web tech is not my strong suit.

Comment: have you tried the tutorials on parse.com's website? They are very comprehensive.

Comment: i have checked them out, but was hoping to save myself a lot of time and heartbreak if others have gone down this path :)  still pretty new to iOS and objective-c so non-Apple frameworks are challenging for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually got this answered at a Parse.com company event here in SF, and since then have also learned A LOT about Facebook integration and posting.

**The long story short is: Parse.com cannot serve as the only object in your web stack if you want to post Facebook Open Graph Stories.**

In addition to simply hosting an image, Facebook Open Graph Stories require two things:

1. A public HTML page that Facebook's servers can reach. This page serves Facebook meta data that Facebook uses to determine how to present your image object.
2. A click-through link to a landing page that contains your image object.

I ended up using a Tumblr blog to host my photos, because you can 'hack' their Themes to include your own HTML headers that support FB OG Stories. It's not perfect, but for a guy without a web stack, it gets the job done!